# Css border-radius not going around my div container

Tags: html, css

I have a rounded border with css `border-radius` which isn't going around my container2 `div`.
You can see it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad5zy/1/).
For some reason it shows partial but is above the container2 and not around it.

Can anyone help me with why its doing this?

Comment: because of float left in .left-column2 , remove it + to fix issue with top border change border-top:4px to border-top-width:4px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the property

```
"float :left"
```

of your inner div elements. You have specified "float:left" for your inner div but not outer div so this disrupts the proper formatting of the dom elements and hence only setting the border property separately for outer div. Either remove "float:left" from all divs css or add them in all . 
Also remove the

```
border-top:4px;
```

property from .container2 to display the top border correctly. Here is the working fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Ad5zy/8/
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `overflow: hidden` so the content won't overflow from the container.

Also you should remove the `border-top: 4px`. It makes the top border white.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/Ad5zy/5/)

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested and it fixed the top border but the border isnt going around container2 still.

Answer (score 1):

```
   try this 
   .container2 {border: 2px solid #006699;
    border-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-right:4px;
    padding-left:4px;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
     border-radius: 15px;
     float:left;//you miss this
```

Comment: add float:left; in your style style sheet

Comment: I see someone had mentioned that previously so i will have to give the best answer to them :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-top: 4px;` for `.container2`

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad5zy/6/)

Comment: The border still does not wrap the entire div element with nested divs . It just displays the omitted top border.

Comment: Give overflow: hidden to it